# How come the stack cannot be increased during runtime in most operating system?

Tags: c, operating-system, stack-allocation

Is it to avoid fragmentation? Or some other reason? A set lifetime for a memory allocation is a pretty useful construct, compared to `malloc()` which has a manual lifetime.

Comment: Why is this tagged with C? I don't see any C specific here - except a reference to `malloc`.

Comment: @4386427 What's a better tag?

Comment: Maybe operating-systems would be more appropriate.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Can you write that as an answer, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space used for stack is increased and decreased frequently during program execution, as functions are called and return. The **maximum** space allowed for the stack is commonly a fixed limit.

In older computers, memory was a very limited resource, and it may still be in small devices. In these cases, the hardware capability may impose a necessary limit on the maximum stack size.

In modern systems with plenty of memory, a great deal may be available for stack, but the maximum allowed is generally set to some lower value. That provides a means of catching “runaway” programs. Generally, controlling how much stack space a program uses is a neglected part of software engineering. Limits have been set based on practical experience, but we could do better.<sup>1</sup>

Theoretically, a program could be given a small initial limit and could, if it finds itself working on a “large” problem, tell the operating system it intends to use more. That would still catch most “runaway” programs while allowing well crafted programs to use more space. However, by and large we design programs to use stack for program control (managing function calls and returns, along with a modest amount of space for local data) and other memory for the data being operated on. So stack space is largely a function of program design (which is fixed) rather than problem size. That model has been working well, so we keep using it.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> For example, compilers could report, for each routine that does not use objects with run-time variable size, the maximum space used by the routine in any path through it. Linkers or other tools could report, for any call tree [hence without loops] the maximum stack space used. Additional tools could help analyze stack use in call graphs with potential recursion.

Answer (score 5):

> How come the stack cannot be increased during runtime in most operating system?

This is wrong for Linux. On recent Linux systems, each thread has its own [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (see [pthreads(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)), and an application could (with clever tricks) increase some call stacks using [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and [mremap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) after querying the call stacks thru `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and use `/proc/self/maps`) like e.g. [pmap(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) does.

Of course, such code is architecture specific, since in some cases the call stack grows towards increasing addresses and in other cases towards decreasing addresses.

Read also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) and the [OSDEV](https://www.osdev.org/) wiki, and study the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/).

BTW, Appel's book [*Compiling with Continuations*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/compiling-with-continuations/7CA9C36DCE78AD82218E745F43A4E740), his old paper [*Garbage Collection can be faster than Stack Allocation*](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Eappel/papers/45.pdf) and this paper on [*Compiling with Continuations and LLVM*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08842.pdf) could interest you, and both are very related to your question: sometimes, there is almost "no call stack" and it makes no sense to "increase it".

Comment: Is that a supported thing like a call for “make my stack bigger” or a do-it-yourself thing like “find where the end of my stack mapping is and map some more memory beyond it”? If the latter, how do you find where the end of the stack mapping is? Something explicitly given to tell you where the end is (or, equivalently, how big the stack is) or something else?